# Present month average values should not be passed to average table

Tags: mysql

i want to add average month values in to avg_month_val1 table from reg_data3 but there is error query is not work properly. present monthly averages should not insert to  avg_month_val table.error is unknown column name in having clause. please help me

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1` ( 
    `year` , `month` ,  `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , 
    `rainfall` , `max_temp` , `min_temp` )
SELECT
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as year,
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as month,
    round(avg(evep),2),
    round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
    round(sum(rainfall),2),
    round(AVG(max_temp),2),
    round(avg(min_temp),2) 
FROM reg_data3 
GROUP BY 
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')),
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
HAVING 
    (year(str_to_date(date  , '%Y-%m-%d')) <> year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    AND month(str_to_date(date , '%Y-%m-%d')) <> month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ) 
ORDER BY 1 Desc;
```

Comment: this question no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAVING can only match columns which are SELECT'ed in your output - so you can replace the year() and month() parts with the matching columns:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1` ( 
    `year` , `month` ,  `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , 
    `rainfall` , `max_temp` , `min_temp` )
SELECT
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as year,
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as month,
    round(avg(evep),2),
    round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
    round(sum(rainfall),2),
    round(AVG(max_temp),2),
    round(avg(min_temp),2) 
FROM reg_data3 
GROUP BY 
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')),
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
HAVING 
    ( `year` <> year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    AND `month` <> month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ) 
ORDER BY 1 Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would deselect the unwanted data before grouping, so the processed rows are less:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1` ( 
    `year` , `month` ,  `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , 
    `rainfall` , `max_temp` , `min_temp` )
SELECT
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as year,
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as month,
    round(avg(evep),2),
    round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
    round(sum(rainfall),2),
    round(AVG(max_temp),2),
    round(avg(min_temp),2) 
FROM reg_data3 
WHERE str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d') < cast(curdate() - 
                                           day(curdate() - interval 1 day)  
                                           AS date)
GROUP BY 
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')),
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
ORDER BY 1 Desc;
```

Also I would strongly recommend altering the date column to a real date column, to prevent the transforming from str to date. Because this is consuming a lot of processing power if you process a lot rows.